# How to print A5 2-up saddle-stitched booklets from PDF with manual dupex?

Tags: printing, document

I have a simple A4 laser printer and want to print A5 booklet like described [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/ways-print-pdfs.html). I open the PDF in the viewer but in the printer setting are no options to achieve it. Even manual duplex of even and odd pages is impossible to set up.

Comment: Never tried, but saved these: SCript 16 A& to a4 booklet
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2135458&p=12602855
Print alt pages to make booklets:
Postscript
http://dsl.org/cookbook/cookbook_25.html

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/printing-booklet-duplex.html.en  or just type booklet into the search bar for this stie.

Answer (score 0):

Use [pdfbook](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdfbook) from `texlive-extra-utils` to create a booklet and print that.